# Jasmine - Error: jasmine-fixture requires jQuery to be defined at window.jQuery or window.$

Tags: javascript, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I am just learning and trying to test my javascript with Jasmine framework. 
My javascript is just setting placeholder attribute of textarea to blank.

```
function clearPlaceholderTextOnFocus(i) {
    i.placeholder = '';
}
```

I am calling this function on onClick event of textarea.
I wrote below code in Jasmine spec-

```
describe("Test suite for clearPlaceholderTextOnFocus",function(){
it("Should set placeholder to blank", function(){

var i=affix('textarea[name="message"][placeholder="write your message here..."]');

clearPlaceholderTextOnFocus(i);

var placeholderval = $('i').attr('placeholder'); 
expect(placeholderval).toHaveValue('');
});

});
```

When I run this code by double clicking on SpecRunner.html then I am getting below error -

Error: jasmine-fixture requires jQuery to be defined at window.jQuery or window.$

Below is my SpecRunner.html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Jasmine Spec Runner v2.5.2</title>

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="lib/jasmine-2.5.2/jasmine_favicon.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jasmine-2.5.2/jasmine.css">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/core.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/jasmine-2.5.2/jasmine.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/jasmine-2.5.2/jasmine-html.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/jasmine-2.5.2/boot.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/jasmine-2.5.2/jasmine-jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/jasmine-2.5.2/jasmine-fixture.js"></script>

  <!-- include source files here... -->
  <script src="src/myfirst.js"></script> 

  <!-- include spec files here...  -->
  <script src="spec/myfirstSpec.js"></script> 

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

What is wrong with my spec code? or do i need any other setup to run this?

Update - Including

Comment: Try moving the jquery script tag up to before the jasmine-fixtures dependency.

Comment: Thanks! I tried moving it up but still getting same error. I have updated my SpecRunner.html file in question.

Comment: Your source is not the full jquery library. if you look at the source it is not defining jQuery globally: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/core.js -- try including the jquery.js file

Comment: Including jQuery core does not define window.jQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/29g153L3/

Comment: Including <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script> works. But now getting this error -  TypeError: expect(...).toHaveValue is not a function

Comment: I'm inclined to believe that error. toHaveValue is probably not a function

Comment: How I can check if placeholder attribute is now set to blank otherwise? Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Did you import Jquery in your SpecRunner.html? Like this

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/core.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not import before but now I added it and tested ... But still I am getting same error. I have updated my complete SpecRunner.html file in question.

Comment: Why a negative vote even though it helped the OP realize they missed to import the jasmine.js file